# JAVA Mostrar por consola la fecha con el mes especificado

Tags: java, date

tengo una clase llama Socio la cual crea un socio con su nombre, nif y fecha de alta.

Al crearlo en el main tengo que hacer que muestre por consola exactamente:

Socio: Antonio Romero Nif: 12345678X Fecha de alta: 30 abril 2015

He intentado lo siguiente (recordar que tengo una clase llama Socio con estos tres atributos con su toString y la fecha la tengo con un LocalDate)

```
    DateTimeFormatter fechaFormateada = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/LL/yyyy");
    Socio socio = new Socio("Antonio Romero", "12345678X",
    LocalDate.parse("30/04/2015", fechaFormateada));
    System.out.println(socio.toString());
```

Y me muestra lo siguiente:

Socio: Antonio Romero Nif: 12345678X Fecha de alta: 2015-04-30

Me falla la fecha, tengo que poner que sea  30 abril 2015, en el código anterior es algo que he intentado hacer con DateTimeFormatter y parse pero no sé si es algo que tenga que utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un método que le da el formato que quieres a la fecha:

```
public String formatearFecha(String fecha) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatoInicial = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    SimpleDateFormat formatoFinal = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
    Date date = formatoInicial.parse(fecha);
    return formatoFinal.format(date);
}
```

La llamas así: `formatearFecha("30/04/2015")` y te devuelve: `30 abril 2015`. Debes encerrar la llamada en un bloque `try-catch` por si falla.